# How to relax our strained eyes

Tags: relaxation

After the advancement of technology we have hell number of Gadgets with various types of Display(led, lcd, amoled etc.). Due to which we mostly tend to be glued to the screens and are straining the eyes 
Eye is the most important part of the body which gets neglected by everyone(In Gym we target only the particular body muscle which gets improved  but what about the eyes ,a pity for those whose Job demands eyes to see their screens). Isn't there any exercise to get relief from the strained eyes and improved our ability of the eyes.

A pictorial exercise for the eyes would be an added advantage.

**Note**:-Please avoid giving medications as this question is strictly restrticted to eyes and its improvement and not a medication issue. I purely want exercise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To help keep your eyes in top shape, there's a large number of exercises you can do while working on electronic screens. I grabbed these ideas [from](http://www.lifehacker.co.in/jugaad/Relax-Your-Eyes-to-Improve-Eyesight-in-A-Natural-Way/articleshow/28505810.cms) [some](http://voices.yahoo.com/five-great-tips-relax-eyes-while-working-on-2423852.html) [quick](http://www.wikihow.com/Protect-Your-Eyes-when-Using-a-Computer) [research](http://www.howtogeek.com/54872/how-to-avoid-computer-eye-strain-and-keep-your-eyes-healthy/)

1. **Roll your eyes.**
   This will help both by removing the strain of looking at the screen and by giving the muscles controlling your eye a slight workout.
2. **Close your eyes.** This break will allow your eyes to reset, reducing the load of a long day of looking at a screen.
3. **Focus your eyes.** You can focus on your nose, then focus on something far away, and repeat; this will help reduce the impact of looking at a screen a set distance away for a long time.

In addition, there are a number of strategies you can follow which, while not eye exercises, will make a day of looking at a screen far easier on your eyes. (same sources)

1. **Take breaks.** Whether taking a break to do one of the above exercises, or just to walk around, a break gives your eyes a chance to relax. Try to break at least for a minute or two once an hour.
2. **Position monitor correctly.** Your monitor should be between 1.5-2.5 feet from your eyes, and 1/2-1 foot lower than the plane of your eyesight. This positioning will help with refraction and will make it easier on your eyes to view the screen.
3. **Enlarge text.** Moving to a higher text size on editors or a higher zoom level on browsers will reduce the strain on your eyes.
4. **Fix lighting.** Make sure that your computer screen is set to a brightness level that feels comfortable on your eyes, and try to position external light sources so that they don't interfere with your view of the screen. Lighting can have a big impact on how hard your eyes are working to see the screen.

The best strategy here is to limit screen time, but with many jobs, that's not an option. When viewing a screen for many hours a day is necessary, these exercises and habits will help to reduce the impact on your eyes.